Mathematica 13.1: How can I set PageWidth and Word Wrapping?
Sorry about the following beginner's question but it is driving me nuts:
In Mathematica 13.1, lines in my notebooks don't word-wrap on the screen.
Using Format/Word Wrapping/Wrap at Window Width in the menu doesn't change a thing.
At the suggestion of ChatGPT, I have used Option Inspector for Scope ´Global Preferences´ to set ´LineBreakWithin´ to "Automatic" and ´PageWidth´ to WindowWidth. For Scope ´Selected Notebook´ I couldn't change PageWidth from Infinity.
Thank you for helping me out!

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Can you perhaps post a screenshot of how your window looks like? Also, if you go to Format > Option Inspector, then select Global Preferences and search for LineBreakWithin, what are the settings? These are mine.
